# Avoiding the lost of a user and the lost of more than 20k points

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

Using this query [get post list of a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=98602) or [answers of a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/942475/answers-of-a-deleted-user?userid=98602) and [estimated reputation of a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1063963/estimated-reputation-of-a-deleted-user) I could realize that an specific no longer user  had 722 answers and approximately 28753 points! and yet decided to delete their account.

It's not the first time that I witness such incredibly deletions. Another user whom had his real name, (I know because I once had a discussion with him and that's how I could link his name) he had approximately 24799 points and 584 answers.

I think we should do something about it because you don't get easily more than 20k nor you  easily  answer more than 500 answers. Takes a lot of time, effort, etc.

I have thought in this:

To have something like "Please think twice, it's very likely that you'll regret" additionally to the default one day to wait for the deletion.

If the first doesn't work, then at least 
we should do something about it with their points. We could suggest the user that had decided to delete their account to spend their rep in bounties to difficult questions or questions that the user likes or in outstanding answers.

Comment: If they decided to had their account deleted, they obviously do not care about the rep. points. And you cannot transfer their points to anyone else, since this is their points. Essentially nothing is lost. The Questions/Answers are still on site.

Comment: And when they chose to delete theiry account, they have IIRC 24 hours before the account really got deleted and one can stop the deletion in that 24 hours. Some with tons of answers might take even longer.

Comment: There was also an user with >100k rep who deleted his account: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19245/515527

Comment: I'm not sure why you would characterize this action as "crazy", and I am not sure that I understand why you would the number of imaginary internet points associated to an account should matter.  If a user decides that they no longer want to be part of this community, they probably also don't consider their imaginary internet points to be all that valuable, either.

Comment: @LeBlanc A minute of silence for that account..

Comment: " they obviously do not care about the rep. points. " I know, but they could 'donate' them. For instance if they don't wanna know about anything about their account, then somebody else (mods or trustworthy person) could 'manage' their account and do something nice with their points (under the donation consent of the user of course)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I said "crazy" because you don't get for free more than 20k, that is, it takes lot of your time, effort,etc. and then to just deliberately decide to delete it?// Those _imaginary internet points_ matter a lot. Some users out there only help you if you did put a bounty in your question, they also matter for your curriculum (in case you have your real name, of course), and many other privileges.

Comment: @XanderHenderson but if you don't care about the imaginary points, then you could share them :) .Maybe in old (say before 2015) unanswered questions or questions that most people don't wanna spend time in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not discuss specific user deletions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that's not fair, it takes only one of your vote to do that. You should let the community to vote (which requires 5 votes).

Comment: It's been standard policy since more-or-less the conception of site that we do not discuss private matters publicly. Moderators are not allowed to discuss this by their agreement when they join the moderator team of their site, and we expect regular users to also respect the privacy of users who decide to leave the site. If you want to dispute this, you are free to raise *this* topic for discussion, but currently (and in general) I am very much against discussions which are entirely speculative.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see. I think I did a mistake with writing this question: 'Why to do such crazy things?' and the title. The other two are fine, have nothing to do with privacy. If I delete the question, would be in standards?

Comment: "Those imaginary internet points matter a lot." @user486983 No, they really don't.  They matter a lot to some people.  To someone who has determined that they don't matter, THE DON'T MATTER.  Why go through the time and effort of "donating" them by offering bounties if you have already determined that you don't want to be associate with MSE any longer?

Comment: @XanderHenderson That's why I said --somebody else (mods or trustworthy person) could 'manage' their account--  you can be disassociate with MSE (you just leave) and let other to do something with the points (anonymously donated, if that works).

Comment: @user486983 Why?  XP on MSE is not a zero sum game.  In the "economy" of reputation, nothing is lost.  Moreover, the idea of reputation on MSE is that it should emulate reputation in the real world---you earn it through individual interactions with others.  Redistributing the reputation of deleted accounts runs counter that that philosophy.  And, again, they are *imaginary internet points*.  In the grand scheme of things, they simply don't matter.

Comment: @XanderHenderson "XP on MSE is not a zero sum game" huh? // I just think those points are going to 'trash' when someone deletes their account. They could have been used in benefit of mse. I was also thinking that we could spread them in already given answers, outstanding answer :)

Comment: @user486983 The idea that reputation should be "redistributed" if a user leaves would make sense if there were a fixed amount of reputation on MSE, i.e. if reputation were a zero sum game (the only way for me to gain reputation is for others to lose it).  Rep on MSE is **not** a zero sum game---anyone can create rep *ex nihilo* by upvoting.  Under this model, it simply does not make sense to redistribute reputation.

Comment: @XanderHenderson when you put a bounty, you start playing a zero sum game 
 because you are gonna lose points and the person who answers will gain reputation from you.

Comment: @user486983 As a 100k user, my account only really has two things of real value to me: *(1)* no barrier in the rare instances I feel like commenting/answer, and *(2)* a relatively easy way to locate and browse things I know I've written in the past. But it also has things I value negatively, the clearest being associating my handle with the SE network. If it does so, when the latter outweighs the former, I will once again submit my account for deletion -- and that time I will not go radio silent so I actually get the confirmation request and respond to it.

Comment: @Hurkyl (3) help in your curriculum? (4) practicing your math skills?, etc. :P  May I know why it 'being associating my handle with the SE network'  bothers you?

Comment: @user486983 Neither of those things are contingent on retaining ownership of *this specific account*. One can browse without having an account at all, and if I were really inspired to write something after having deleted it, a new throwaway account would achieve that.

Comment: ... as for being associated with SE, in the past, my issue was over mse seeming to degenerate towards the homework mill paradigm and a few specific users. Today, both the licensing and CoC debacles make the company look like something I *really* don't want to be supporting *at all*.

Comment: @Hurkyl my points (3) and (4) were meant specifically for your case, I wanted you to see other cool things that might be of good value while being here.//well, perhaps you'd change your mind at some point..who knows? :)

Comment: people who want to.practice math skills, have dr math, purplemath, khan academy, computer algebra systems like PARI/GP, etc. what makes SE special is the Q&A for potentially research level mathematics.

Comment: Hopefully you do something about all these (^◔ᴥ◔^)

Comment: @user14972 I can't believe you deleted your account ◔̯◔ And why was I not here that day?

Answer (score 6):

While I cannot speculate on specific cases, I've seen high-reputation accounts get deleted for a variety of reasons. For example,

- dissatisfaction with the site direction,
- disagreement with mods,
- getting suspended for irregular voting patterns.

As for your suggestions to add a warning and grace period, I believe it's already the case. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of that warning note and grace period (that's what I meant with 'the default one day to wait for the deletion'), but sincerely I don't see it as enough or complete. I think it's necessary "Please think twice, it's very likely that you'll regret" and perhaps in big capital font and probably even more because it's not just a 1k deletion (that you'll probably recover in, say some month(s)) it's more than 20k.

Comment: With regards to your first point, when you go to 'Delete Profile', your account will only be deleted if you click the box saying 'I have read the information stated above'. If you do not feel this is adequate to prevent accidental/impulsive deletions (which I doubt there are many of), you can ask a new question regarding this.

Comment: And about your second point, I don't think there are many people would want to rejoin the site after they have deleted their account. If the user has made their decision honestly and in good faith, there should be no reason to stop their personal  decision. In fact, if SE put a notice with big capital letters, it would be seen as clingy or perhaps greedy for SE to intervene, which would not go well given the [recent situation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30735/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-sudden-changes-at-se) SE has found itself in.

Comment: @TobyMak About the second point, some people are impulsive which means that in a 'mad moment' are capable of doing weird things but after some days or probably months, they realize about their mistakes. Given that we don't know who we are dealing with _but_ we do know all their hard work they had done in mse, we should perhaps thinking about giving more than one day of grace period.// I haven't fully understand the recent situation link that you mention

Comment: I think your suggestion about extending the grace period is reasonable. From my experience, other sites have longer grace periods: for example, Khan Academy has 7 days. Also, don't worry about understanding the link I gave. The situation is very complicated, and no one (not even moderators or SE staff) have a full picture of the situation.

Comment: @TobyMak Ok. Would be a good idea if you use pings @

Comment: There are many reasons that one wish to join the site with a new account. They might be tried of answering comments left under their answers (which might be a lot), they might want a new identity to participate @TobyMak

Comment: @user486983 It seems that you are rooting in the assumption that reputation is a reason to participate. For a lot of users, this is just not true. The rep. point is of no importance in the first place, so there's nothing "mad" about deleting their accounts.

Comment: I can see it both ways.